# Using Winsockets to connect to an URL

Tags: sockets, winapi, asynchronous, client

I have a simple win32 app which I use to post to usenet. I also use it to send email.

A snippet of code for usenet posting is like this:

```
...
WSAAsyncSelect(conn_sock,mywin,nRet,FD_CONNECT|FD_READ|FD_WRITE|FD_CLOSE|FD_ACCEPT);
lpServEnt = getservbyname("nntp", "tcp");   
saServ.sin_family = AF_INET;
saServ.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)*lpHostEnt->h_addr_list);
nRet = connect((SOCKET)conn_sock,(LPSOCKADDR)&saServ,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
... etc.
```

It works well. When I change "nntp" to "smtp" I can send email. If it is "http" my code does not work as well. I can connect and GET/POST if the address is "localhost", "127,0,01" or "192.168.0.5" but not if I use "195.nn.nn.nn" or "www.somesite.com" etc.

What am I missing? I am trying to avoid using `HttpOpenRequest()` etc. functions and use the `send()` `recv()` etc. instead.

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` requires an IP address in numeric format.

`getservbyname()` is intended to retrieve the IP address and port of a service provider that is registered in a services database for easy lookup.  For instance, if a client is on a corporate network that has its own SMTP server, it makes sense that an SMTP service provider might be registered so `getservbyname("smtp")` or `getaddrinfo("smtp")` can be used.  It is less likely that there is an HTTP service provider registered, though.  And most end users DO NOT even have a service provider database installed on their PCs, or it is empty.

If you have a hostname ("smtp.somesite.com", "nntp.somesite.com", "www.somesite.com", etc), you need to use `gethostbyname()` or `getaddrinfo()` to resolve the hostname to an IP address:

```
hostent *lpHostEnt = gethostbyname("nntp.somesite.com");   
if ((lpHostEnt) && (lpHostEnt->h_addrtype == AF_INET))
{
    saServ.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saServ.sin_addr = *((LPIN_ADDR)(lpHostEnt->h_addr));
    saServ.sin_port = htons(119);
    nRet = connect(conn_sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&saServ, sizeof(saServ));
}
```

```
addr_info hints = {0};
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addr_info *addr = NULL;

nRet = getaddrinfo("nntp.somesite.com", "119", &hints, &addr);
if (nRet == 0)
{
    nRet = connect(conn_sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(addr);
}
```

If you have an IP address in string format instead ("127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.5", etc), you need to use `inet_addr()` or `getaddrinfo()` to convert the string to numeric format:

```
saServ.sin_family = AF_INET;
saServ.sin_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.5");
saServ.sin_port = htons(119);
nRet = connect(conn_sock, (LPSOCKADDR)&saServ, sizeof(saServ));
```

```
addr_info hints = {0};
hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

addr_info *addr = NULL;

nRet = getaddrinfo("192.168.0.5", "119", &hints, &addr);
if (nRet == 0)
{
    nRet = connect(conn_sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(addr);
}
```

These are the most common scenarios that your code needs to support.  `getservbyname()` is not commonly used.